# «Как обычно»: обособление с двух сторон

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, наречия, авторская-пунктуация

**Он хотел сказать что-то ободряющее и разрядить обстановку, но вышло(,) как обычно(,) наоборот.**
Необходимо знать, нужны ли в этом предложении указанные запятые?
Возможно, здесь уместны два варианта, один от автора, а второй — чтобы на дискуссии не нарываться, чисто по правилам. Но хотелось бы знать точный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В справочнике Лопатина:

> § 89. Всегда выделяются сочетания как правило, как исключение, как
>   следствие, как всегда, как сейчас, как нарочно, как например, как
>   теперь и др., кроме тех, что включаются в состав сказуемого: Он
>   пришел, как всегда, неожиданно (Пауст.); Как сейчас, помню тихий
>   июльский день (Фад.); Как правило, в этих местах бывают обильные дожди
>   (ср.: В этих местах обильные дожди бывают как правило).

http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=260

В Вашем случае сочетание не входит в состав сказуемого, следовательно обособляется: *Он хотел сказать что-то ободряющее и разрядить обстановку, но вышло, как обычно, наоборот*.

Answer (score 5):

[как обычно](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/172826/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE)
**I.** *нареч. качеств.-обстоят.*
**1.** Так, как всегда; привычно.
*отт.* Употребляется как вводное словосочетание, указывающее на то, что именно таким образом — как всегда — протекает действие.
**2.** Так, как все, ничем не выделяясь среди других; обыкновенно, заурядно.
*отт.* Употребляется как вводное словосочетание, указывающее на то, что действие происходит постоянно или очень часто.
**3.** Употребляется как несогласованное определение.
**II.** *предик.*
**1.** Оценочная характеристика ситуации, чьих-либо действий как являющихся привычными.
**2.** Оценочная характеристика каких-либо качеств, чьих-либо действий как являющихся такими, как у всех.

Вводное слово «как обычно» чаще всего обособляется. Тогда его можно без потери смысла изъять из предложения (по значению — вариант **I. 1**; *...но вышло наоборот*).

*Он хотел сказать что-то ободряющее и разрядить обстановку, но вышло, **как обычно,** наоборот.*
*Но там, на корабле, в светлых, сияющих люстрами и мрамором залах, был, **как обычно,** людный бал в эту ночь* (И. Бунин. Господин из Сан-Франциско).

Авторское восприятие (и, соответственно, авторская пунктуация) — вещь особенная.
Без контекста можно только предполагать. Если представить, что автор хочет сделать упор на обычности происходящего (так — наоборот — происходит почти всегда; по значению — вариант **II. 1**), то пунктуация возможна такая.

*Он хотел сказать что-то ободряющее и разрядить обстановку, **но вышло как обычно** — наоборот.*
*А дальше всё опять **было как обычно*** (В. Пелевин. Синий фонарь).

(Или даже такая: *Он хотел сказать что-то ободряющее и разрядить обстановку, но вышло как обычно.* [как именно? — пояснение] *Наоборот.*)

[КАК ОБЫЧНО, *вводное слово*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_336)